# Problemas registrando usuario en php

Tags: php

recientemente he creado un registro de usuario en un archivo register.php y un archivo que verifica, recibe y envia los datos a la db mediante registration_login.php

pero una vez que quiero entrar a localhos/archivo/register.php

me envia directamente a index.php **no me muesta la pagina de registro**. les dejo el codigo para **register.php** y **registration_login.php**

**register.php**

```
<?php include('config.php') ?>

<?php include('registration_login.php') ?>

<h2>Registro de Usuario</h2>


<form method="post" action="register.php">
  <?php include('errors.php') ?>

<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">

<label>Email</label>
<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">

<label>Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password_1">

<label>Confirm password</label>
<input type="password" name="password_2">

<button type="submit" name="reg_user">Register</button>

<p>
  Already  a member? <a href="login.php">Sign In</a>
</p>
```

**registration_login.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

//inicializo variables, almacenaran datos
$username = "";
$email = "";
$errors = array();

//conecto a la db
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');

//registro de usuarios
if(isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
   //recibe todos los input values del form y los guarda en las variables declaradas
   $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['username']);
   $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['email']);
   $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['password_1']);
   $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $POST['password_2']);


   //validacion del form: "SE ASEGURA QUE LA FORMA ESTE BIEN LLENADA"
   // por cada verificacion en caso de ser negativa se iran agregando los errores al final del array dentro de la variable errors.php!!!!!!!
   if(empty($username)) {
       array_push($errors, 'username is required');
   }
   if(empty($email)) {
       array_push($erros, 'email is required');
   }

   if(empty($password_1)) {
       array_push($errors, 'password is required');
   }

   if($password_1 != $password_2) {
       array_push($errors, 'passwords do not match, please check');
   }
}


//antes de enviar chequear con una consulta a la db que el usuario o email ingresado no exista

//creo una variable que guarde la informacion de la consulta
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $user_check_query);
$users = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


//advertencia mediantes sentencias if para la variable user
if($user) {
    //toma de los valores de la variable user el username en la bd
    if($user['username'] === $username) {
        array_push($errors, 'username already exists');
    }

    if($user['email'] === $email) {
        array_push($errors, 'email already exists');
    }
}


//si no hay ningun error, registra el usuario en la db insertando los datos guardados en las variables

//si los errores en la form == 0
if(count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); //encripta la password antes de guardarla en la bd

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
          VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";

    mysqli_query($db, $query);
    //variables superglobales de session, almacena datos del usuario para las sesiones
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['success'] = 'you are logged in';
    //redirecciona
    header('location: index.php');
}

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es por que en register.php  esta llamando a registration_login.php desde

```
<?php include('registration_login.php') ?>
```

Al ser llamado veo que al final de registration_login.php tiene este codigo

```
if(count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1); //encripta la password antes de guardarla en la bd
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password)
              VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
   mysqli_query($db, $query);
   //variables superglobales de session, almacena datos del usuario para las sesiones
   $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
   $_SESSION['success'] = 'you are logged in';
  //redirecciona
   header('location: index.php');
}
```

yo como le dice el if que no tiene ningun error(osea 0),  este por medio de la funcion

```
 header('location: index.php');
```

Lo redirecciona automaticamente al index.php

Comment: Eso estoy viendo, dejame aclarar un error que me salio cuando volvi a entrar jaja y podre ver tu consejo en el codigo amigo

Comment: Funciono efectivamente